# Anchor tags in IE 10 shows as empty text node

Tags: html, text, internet-explorer-10

Anchor tags in IE 10 are being displayed as empty text nodes, the solution I already found here was adding display block and zoom 1, but those aren't working:

```
<ul style="list-style-position:outside;list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a href="http://google.com/" style="display:block;zoom:1;">Google</a></li> <!-- nothing is being displayed -->
    <li><a href="http://google.com/" style="display:block;zoom:1;"><b>Google</b></a></li> <!-- the link is being displayed as bold as aspected -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Also tried position absolute, display inline-block, min-width & min-height, overflow auto. Nothing seems to work... Do I have a bad case of a peek a boo bug? :P

Comment: whatever the reason was, it looks like it works now: http://jsfiddle.net/Ffk9q/

Answer (score 0):

Dirty workaround:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after the text of the anchor tag, just before the closing </a> tag.

```
<ul style="list-style-position:outside;list-style-type:none;">
  <li><a href="http://google.com/" style="display:block;zoom:1;">Google </a></li> <!-- nothing is being displayed -->
  <li><a href="http://google.com/" style="display:block;zoom:1;"><b>Google</b> </a></li> <!-- the link is being displayed as bold as aspected -->
</ul>
```